# Designing tail recursion using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, tail-recursion

I was trying out the following example provide in the [talk](https://youtu.be/4tEi86h8-TM?t=32m30s) to understand the tail recursion in java8.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TailCall<T> {
    TailCall<T> apply();

    default boolean isComplete() {
        return false;
    }

    default T result() {
        throw new Error("not implemented");
    }

    default T get() {
        return Stream.iterate(this, TailCall::apply).filter(TailCall::isComplete)
                                                .findFirst().get().result();
    }
}
```

Utility class to use the TailCall

```
public class TailCalls {
    public static <T> TailCall<T> call(final TailCall<T> nextcall) {
        return nextcall;
    }

    public static <T> TailCall<T> done(final T value) {
        return new TailCall<T>() {
            @Override
            public boolean isComplete() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public T result() {
                return value;
            }

            @Override
            public TailCall<T> apply() {
                throw new Error("not implemented.");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the use of the of Tail recursion :

```
public class Main {

    public static TailCall<Integer> factorial(int fact, int n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            return TailCalls.done(fact);
        } else {
            return TailCalls.call(factorial(fact * n, n-1));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factorial(1, 5).get());
        }
}
```

It worked correctly, but I feel like we don't require the `TailCall::get` to compute the result. As per my understanding we can directly compute the result using:

```
System.out.println(factorial(1, 5).result());
```

instead of:

```
System.out.println(factorial(1, 5).get());
```

Please let me know if I am missing the gist of `TailCall::get`.

Comment: fwiw technique is called [trampolining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)) – and yes, while you *can* use this technique to make a recursive procedure stack-safe, you *cannot* implement actual tail call elimination in a program using a language that does not support tail recursion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a mistake in the example. It will just preform plain recursion, without tail call optimization. You can see this by adding `Thread.dumpStack` to the base case:

```
if (n == 1) {
    Thread.dumpStack();
    return TailCalls.done(fact);
}
```

The stack trace will look something like:

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1333)
    at test.Main.factorial(Main.java:14)
    at test.Main.factorial(Main.java:18)
    at test.Main.factorial(Main.java:18)
    at test.Main.factorial(Main.java:18)
    at test.Main.factorial(Main.java:18)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

As you can see there are multiple calls to `factorial`. This means that plain recursion takes place, without the tail call optimization. In that case there is indeed no point in calling `get` since the `TailCall` object you get back from `factorial` already has the result in it.

---

The right way to implement this is to return a new `TailCall` object that defers the actual call:

```
public static TailCall<Integer> factorial(int fact, int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return TailCalls.done(fact);
    }

    return () -> factorial(fact * n, n-1);
}
```

If you also add the `Thread.dumpStack` there will be only 1 call to `factorial`:

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1333)
    at test.Main.factorial(Main.java:14)
    at test.Main.lambda$0(Main.java:18)
    at java.util.stream.Stream$1.next(Stream.java:1033)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at test.TailCall.get(Main.java:36)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Comment: Looking at the video after answering, this is also what the guy giving the talk does. It looks like you missed the `() ->` in the final example.

Comment: Thanks.. I missed the line.

Comment: Just a note on the names... This is not just tail recursion. Although tail recursion is used, this is actually called *trampolining*, which basically consists of transforming tail recursion into iteration, i.e. into a common loop