# Why I got an stack overflow error for LeetCode algorithm #50

Tags: java, stack-overflow

For the LeetCode algorithm problem #50 Pow(x, n). Why I got an stack overflow error if I put checking n is positive or negative within the recursive function? But if I put the checking outside the recursive function then it will accept.
The test case is 1.000  -2147483648

Checking within the recursive function.

```
class Solution {
    public double myPow(double x, int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            x = 1 / x;
            n = -n;
            return myPow(x,n);
        } 

        if (n == 0) {
            return 1.0;
        }
        double half = myPow(x, n / 2);
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return half * half;
        } else {
            return half * half * x;
        }
    }
}
```

Checking outside the recursive function.

```
class Solution {
    private double fastPow(double x, long n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1.0;
        }
        double half = fastPow(x, n / 2);
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return half * half;
        } else {
            return half * half * x;
        }
    }
    public double myPow(double x, int n) {
        long N = n;
        if (N < 0) {
            x = 1 / x;
            N = -N;
        }

        return fastPow(x, N);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is possibly due to *tail-call optimization*, where if a function only calls itself once, the compiler might expand it to make it effectively iterative. In the first example `myPow` is exposed as a public method so cannot be tail-optimized. The code works fine, but the possible range of `n` is limited by stack space. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937160/designing-tail-recursion-using-java-8) for an example.

Comment: For which input values are you getting an unexpected StackOverflowError ?

Comment: I don't get it... it runs perfectly when I tested it??

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to add the test case. It's 1 -2147483648

Answer (score 0):

It's because your exponent (-2147483648, see coments) overflows:

This code

```
System.out.println(  Integer.MIN_VALUE );
System.out.println( -Integer.MIN_VALUE );
System.out.println( Integer.MIN_VALUE == -Integer.MIN_VALUE );
```

prints

```
-2147483648
-2147483648
true
```

From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4):

> For integer values, negation is the same as subtraction from zero. The Java programming language uses two's-complement representation for integers, and the range of two's-complement values is not symmetric, so negation of the maximum negative int or long results in that same maximum negative number. Overflow occurs in this case, but no exception is thrown. For all integer values x, -x equals (~x)+1.

Answer (score -1):

You are encountering a stack overflow error when checking n within the recursive function is due to the recursive nature of the algorithm. When n is a large negative value, each recursive call will decrement n by 1, eventually leading to a stack overflow.

```
class Solution {
    public double myPow(double x, int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            x = 1 / x;
            long N = -(long) n; // Convert n to long to handle large negative values
            return myPowHelper(x, N);
        } else {
            return myPowHelper(x, n);
        }
    }

    private double myPowHelper(double x, long n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1.0;
        }
        double half = myPowHelper(x, n / 2);
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return half * half;
        } else {
            return half * half * x;
        }
    }
}
```

This corrected code performs the check outside the recursive function and converts n to a long value, where it can handle large negative values of n correctly without encountering a stack overflow error.